# AttributeError: type object 'HTTPConnectionPool' has no attribute 'ConnectionCls'

Tags: python, flask, twill

When running nosetests, using Flask-test I keep getting this error:

```
File "/app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twill/browser.py", line 33, in __init__
    cpl.HTTPConnectionPool.old_http = cpl.HTTPConnectionPool.ConnectionCls
AttributeError: type object 'HTTPConnectionPool' has no attribute 'ConnectionCls'
```

Also when trying to run `twill-sh` I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the code also instead of just the stacktrace?

Comment: The code thats making the error is from Twill, it's open source: http://pastebin.com/iJLZkj5Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the version of twill that you are currently using requires a more up-to-date version of the requests library. You should either upgrade requests, via

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

Or downgrade twill, via:

```
pip uninstall twill
pip install -e git+https://github.com/ctb/twill/@79fa302814715a51e6b117eeee0defd2942af3b6#egg=twill
```